# Overwrite an existing phrase in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to write a plugin in wordpress to change an if phrase in wp-includes/comment.php. In PHP you can't override functions unfortunately, but is there any way I can get wordpress to use my phrase instead of the (almost identical) original phrase in comment.php?

I want comments that don't pass the block list to be moved to spam. Normally the comments are moved to trash. This can be solved in comment.php (l. 837):

Original: `$approved = EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS ? 'trash' : 'spam';`

Modified: `$approved = 'spam';`

Now I want to put this in an extra plugin to not change the wordpress core itself, but don't know hot to solve this

Comment: Did you ask this or a similar question fairly recently? Regardless, do you want to change the label, or the key? The lowercase `trash` is the key used internally, and the title case `Trash` is the label that gets translated into different languages. Each problem has a unique solution, so it is important to know which.

Comment: If it is just the key, on [line 852](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/77a972838c495dca96164e9ebfa24780be439e4e/wp-includes/comment.php#L852) of that same file you'll see where the return value is first past through a filter where you could change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress filters for transformation of data